# is it possible to use 2 parameters with dataview.rowfilter? How?

Tags: vb.net

It works with 1 parameter (i_index) but if I also use i_datum, I get an error like: "Conversion from string "park_id = 100" to type 'Long' is not valid."

```
Public Function detail_kalender(ByVal i_index As Int16, ByVal i_datum As Date) As DataRowView
    Dim dv As DataView
    Dim anyrow As DataRowView
    dv = New DataView

    With dv

        .Table = myds.Tables("kalender")
        .AllowDelete = True
        .AllowEdit = True
        .AllowNew = True
        .RowFilter = "park_id = " & i_index And "datum =" & i_datum


    End With
    anyrow = dv.Item(0) 'geeft de eerste rij van de dataview dv

    ' Simple bind to a TextBox control
    dv = mydt_parken.DefaultView
    Return anyrow
    dv.Dispose()
    dv = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: What is the significance of your `i_` prefix?

Comment: i use the i normally if the type is an integer!

Comment: So why have you used it on i_datum?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code you have there for the row filter, it will translate to:

```
.RowFilter = "park_id = 100datum = something"
```

Notice the lack of space between the park_id and next field.  You also need to add "and" (I think?)

Try:

```
.RowFilter = String.Format("park_id = {0} and datum = {1}", i_index.Tostring, i_datum.ToString)
```

You may need to tinker this to include apostrophes depending on the types of your data (i.e. change to

```
... and datum = **'**{1}**'**
```

if it's a string)

EDIT:  In response to your comment.

Have a look on [this page](http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/) for some useful tips.  For dates you use the # symbols.

```
.RowFilter = String.Format("park_id = {0} and datum = #{1}#", i_index.Tostring, i_datum.ToString)
```

EDIT: In response to your second comment ( formatException"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." ):

This is a little trickier.  I'll list a possible quick solution, but by no means the *best* solution.

```
Dim customDateFormat As String = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
.RowFilter = String.Format("park_id = {0} and datum >= #{1}# and datum <= #{2}#", 
                           i_index.ToString, 
                           New DateTime(i_datum.Year, i_datum.Month, i_datum.Day, 0, 0, 0).ToString(customDateFormat),
                           New DateTime(i_datum.Year, i_datum.Month, i_datum.Day, 23, 59, 59).ToString(customDateFormat))
```

Basically, the chances are that when you compare your date's to the date times in the database, you want to ignore the time? (Making an assumption here).  One way of doing this is to compare your database data with your date, ensuring it is between 00:00 AM and 23:59:59 PM.

I've included a customDateFormat string which you can tamper if you need to, in order to reflect your locale.  I know that date constants ignore locale, but I've no idea what it does inside the RowFilter as a string, and whether the database locale has any effect on it.  If the above doesn't work, you can change the date format string to match your locale to see if that helps.

Comment: park_id is an integer and i_datum is a date type ! So, what is the syntax then?

Comment: if i use these solution, i get a formatException"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." Because the type in my database is a dateTime! Do you have a solution for this please?

Answer (score 0):

Try using instead:

```
.RowFilter = "park_id = " & i_index  & " And datum =" & i_datum
```